# Waiting for the response in API servers

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, akka, netty

I have a Netty HTTP server that I use as an API server. The user sends events to the API server and it processes the event on other threads in same server using executor services or a concurrency framework like Akka. I have two options for the response; when I send the event to another thread, either I can wait for the response and write it to the socket or just write acknowledge message back to the socket.

When I wait for the response, the latency of the http requests increases and the number of requests the server can handle decreases. On the other hand, there is no control for back-pressure so we don't know when the server will process the event and I can't inform the user that the server processed the event. However, the number of http requests the server can handle increases because the latencies are quite low for almost all requests.

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        executor.submit(new Event(msg));
        // do not wait for the response
        ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK));
    }
}

public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(new Event(msg));
        future.after(x -> ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK)));
    }
}
```

Since it's an API server, I don't have to wait for the response in order to inform the user that the event is processed because it's simply a write request that doesn't return a response. So which way is the most convenient one for http servers and do you think the second option worth for its performance benefit?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends upon your requirements.  In general a good philosophy to follow is keep things simple. This may mean do the minimum amount of work required and it may mean leave room for extensibility.  If it makes sense for your use case not to provide status back, then what are the reasons you would do this?  However there is typically a tradeoff between being simple and providing enough visibility into the system. It sounds like you are not sure about what is and is not required?

Ask your self the following questions:

1. Can the clients use the return status to do something meaningful?  What can your clients do without this status?
2. Can you foresee the client needs changing in the future to require responses post processing?  (i.e. return status, return body, error codes, etc...)
3. Is your server required to track what is happening all the way from getting the client request to turning that into action on the server?
4. What is your visibility and ability to debug problems?
5. What is the additional complexity and overhead required to add the functionality? Is this acceptable?

These are just a few of the many questions you should be asking your self in this situation.  Based upon the information you provided I'm not sure if it is possible to provide you with a "you should do X" or "you should do Y" answer.  I think you would be best served by re-evaluating your requirements and ask yourself some questions like the ones listed above.